# Probability: Understanding Random Variables

Tags: probability

I am using Ross' A First Course In Probability (4th). On page 113, Example 1d states the following:

> Independent tirals consisting of the flipping of a coin having
>   probability $p$ of coming up heads are continually performed until
>   either a head occurs or a total of $n$ flips is made. If we let $X$
>   denote the number of times the coin is flipped, then $X$ is a random
>   variable taking on one of the values 1, 2, 3, ..., n with respective
>   probabilities
>
> $P\{X=1\} = P\{H\} = p$
>
> $P\{X=2\} = P\{(T,H)\} = (1-p)p$
>
> $P\{X=3\}=P\{(T,T,H)\} = (1-p)^2p$
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> $P\{X=n-1\}=P\{(T,T,...,T,H)\}=(1-p)^{n-2}p$
>
> $P\{X=n\}=\{(T,T,...,T,T),(T,T,...,T,H)\}=(1-p)^{n-1}$

There are a couple of things that are confusing to me here. To my understanding, they are defining $X$ to be "the number of times the coin is flipped until a head occurs or a total of $n$ flips is made." Then, We would have $P\{X\}$ to be

$P\{X = n\} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (1-p)^{i-1}p^i + (1-p)^i$    , isn't it?

Also, wouldn't $P\{X=n\} =(1-p)^{n-1}p$? How does it turn out to be $(1-p)^{n-1}$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $P\{X\}$? As for your second question, that you flip a head or a tale on the $n$-th trial is irrelevant. Hence you could think of $P\{X=n\}$ as being the probability that you flip $n-1$ tales, simply. The formula given is correct. Another way to get $(1-p)^{n-1}$ is to calculate $(1-p)^n+(1-p)^{n-1}p$.

Comment: My mistake, I meant. $P\{X=n\}$. Post updated.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind the first formula you propose? If $p=1$, for example, then $P\{X=1\}=1$ and $P\{X=i\}=0$ for $i=2,3,\ldots,n$. But your formula would give $P\{X=n\}=1$ which is incorrect.

Comment: I'm getting confused, but will give it more thought. My reasoning was that because $X$ represents "the number of times the coin is flipped until either a head occurs or a total of $n$ flips is made", then the combined probability would be $P\{X=n\} = Sum of P\{ith\,toss = H\} (with\, i = 1,..,n) + P\{n\,flips \,are \,made\}$ (which I believe is $(1-p)^n$).

Comment: Hum, $P\{X=n\}$ is only the last term of your sum, that is, $P\{n\text{ flips are made}\}$. I already gave two ways to get $(1-p)^{n-1}$. The second way I gave is just $P\{n\text{ tales are flipped}\}+P\{n-1\text{ tales are flipped and }1\text{ head is flipped}\}$. A third way would be to calculate $1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}P\{X=i\}$. In all cases the result is $(1-p)^{n-1}$.

Comment: Had to reread the book and reread your posts a couple of times and now I get it a little bit better. Now, they start with $P\{X=1\}=P\{H\}=p$, but if we plug in the final formula "$P\{X=n\}=(1-p)^{n-1}$", we would get 1, which makes me wonder whether they started wrong.

Comment: If we plug what? How would we get 1?

Comment: In the very first line of formulas, they have " P{X=1} = P{H} = p ". If we plugin in the general formula " P{X=n}=$(1-p)^{n-1}$ " for n = 1, we would get 1, which is not equal to $p$, which makes me wonder whether they are wrong on the first line.

Comment: $n$ is not an index! $n\geq1$ is a *given* fixed number. $P\{X=n\}$ is not a general formula. A general formula is given in the answer below by **Graham Kemp**. Notice that he uses the index $k$.

Comment: It started making sense and now I am getting confused again. If we were given the fixed number n to be 4, then $X$ would be the random variable that denotes we either flipped 4 times (with no success) or a head occured at our 4th toss. Then, it would make sense for me to think of it as P{X=4} = $q^4 + q^3p$ with q = 1-p. How is it not a general formula o.O? By the way, thanks for the replies so far!

Comment: Suppose $n=4$. Do the experience a number of times. Maybe the first time you will flip a head on the first trial. Then $X$ takes the value $1$ for this realization of the experience. Maybe the second time, you will flip a head for the first time only on the third trial. Then $X$ takes the value $3$ for this realization of the experience. Maybe the third time you will not have flipped a head in the first three trials. Then the experience is over and $X=4$. The probability $P\{X=k\}$ is $(1-p)^{k-1}\cdot p$ where $k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $0\leq p\leq1$ is supposed to be known.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your last post helped me figured it out. I guess I was confusing the concepts used or maybe RVs are supposed to be this confusing for people who don't know about them, hah. Anyway, thanks a lot!!

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

We are running a series of Bernoulli trials, with a probability of success being $p$, and a probability of failure being $1-p$, until we encounter *either* a success or reach the $n^\text{th}$ trial.   $X$ is the count of trials we perform during a run.

For $0\leq k < n$ we have $\mathsf P\{X=k\} = (1-p)^{k-1}\color{silver}{\cdot}p$, which is the probability of $k-1$ consecutive failures followed by $1$ success.

However, for $k=n$ we want the probability of $n-1$ consecutive failures preceding the $n^\text{th}$ *trial*.   The last trial may *either* be a failure or a success because we'll terminate the run either way.   Thus: $\mathsf P\{X=n\}= (1-p)^{n-1}\color{silver}{\cdot 1}$